# PHP - Simple HTML DOM Parser - Getting FATAL ERROR when html is OK

Tags: php, html, dom

I am trying to parse a table and output the a plaintext in another table. I have gotten this far:

```
<?php 
    if (url_exists($url))
    {
        $html = file_get_html($url);
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "URL doesn't exist.";
    }

    if ($html && is_object($html) && isset($html->nodes))
    {
        // Everything checks out
        $table = $html->find('table[border]');
        if (!empty($table))
        {
        $row = $table->find('tr');
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "Fetched page is not ok.";
    }
?>
```

This returns an error:
Fatal error: `Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /var/www/html/jsudimak/mailman/webdev-test1.php on line 78`

Line 78 is this one: `$row = $table->find('tr');`

This means that :

- the html is valid
- the table I am trying to parse is also valid

Therefore, I am bewildered by the fact that the `find()` method is still returning this error.

I have looked into the cause of this error extensively for the past few days and I have yet to find a solution. I have also tried some other parsing tools no still no luck. Help me with this fellow debuggers!!!!

By the way, I am using the Simple HTML Dom Parser to parse the table.

Comment: Have you tried using `$row = $table->find('tr')[0];` ?

Comment: @Nadir and why by this way it should not get error?

Comment: $html->find('table[border]'); and  $table->find('tr'); is both these find function in same class ?

Comment: @fusion3k my wrong, I meant `$table = $html->find('table[border]')[0];` The documentation says that, unless you specify an index in the function `find()`, it will return an array

Comment: ^ this is a good catch!

Comment: @Nadir Oh my... that did the trick. I can't thank you enough. Cheers!!! Post the answer if you will. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `$table = $html->find('table[border]')[0];`

The documentation says that, unless you specify an index in the function `find()`, it will return an array